# JPA - query using conditional JsonManagedReference

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Mysql with Java spring boot application with JPA. I have a one to one relation between two tables (beans) as follows:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "bean1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Bean2WithFK bean2;
```

If i want to add a join condition, how can this be achieved?
The join condition would be to have a row with deleted field false. So in fact the two tables have one to many relation but i want to make it one to one by getting the non soft deleted field

Comment: Use @JoinColumn(name = "", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "")) or

@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bean1table")
@Where(clause="fieldName is null")
public class Bean1{
```